# CRM 2011 html web resource IE compatibility issue

Tags: web, internet-explorer-8, resources, dynamics-crm-2011, compatibility

There has recently been rollup 16 rolled out and applied to an instance of CRM 2011. Everything seems to work fine except a html web resource that will no longer display. We are using IE9 but when the document mode is set to internet explorer 8 the html displays correctly.

I have tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">`into the header tag and amongst other slight variations too no avail.

It definitely worked in the previous rollup and with ie8 document mode.

Is there any way around this without the obvious roll back and to manual set document mode.

Comment: EmulateIE8 still depends on the doctype.  Have you tried ``<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8">``?

Comment: @PaulWay thanks for the response Paul. I have tried using that but it still doesn't not work.

Comment: When you look at debugger tools, what is the document mode?  In an iFrame, you can get trumped.  What is the document mode when you open only the web resource?

Comment: the document mode does not change, i believe the html section with the compatibility code is somehow over-written by the main window/takes no affect.

Comment: What about when you open the web resource by itself?

Answer (score 0):

If the site is on the local network then IE will sometimes ignore the meta tag and force compatibility mode. Not sure if this is your specific problem but it has bit me more than once.

In Internet Explorer there is a Compatibility View Settings dialog which has an option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" disabling this option will cause IE to properly observe the meta tags for local sites.

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone :)